# find the eigenvalue of $A^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $$A = \pmatrix{7&9\\-3&-5},$$

it is a $2\times 2$ matrix.
For every integer $m$, find all eigenvalues of $A^m$, and bases for the corresponding eigenspaces

How to get it?!!

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange.  Have you tried to diagonalize it?

Comment: yes. I know that A=PDP^(-1) Then A^m=P×D(^m)×P^(-1),But I don't know how to get the eigenvalues of A^m, I can't find the relationship between the eigenvalues of A^m and the the eigenvalues ofA

Comment: Do you know the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: For future posts, format any mathematical expressions in your questions using MathJax, as explained [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Now, for your current question: what have you tried so far?  Have you tried to get the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $A$?  Any ideas as to how that could get you the answer you're looking for?

Comment: yes.I know the eigenvalues of A

Comment: So you can calculate $D$... can you calculate $P$?

Comment: Also: for questions on this site, you should always add a summary of what you've tried so far along with the question statement.

Comment: λ1 =6 λ2 =-4  eigenvector V1=(0,0) eigenvector V2=(-3,1) So the diagonal of D is 6 -4  the columns of P is V1 and V2

Comment: But I don't know how to use these information to get the eigenvalues of A^m

Comment: @cecily "Eigenvector $V_1 = (0,0)$" looks like you did a mistake... Eigenvectors are different from $0$ by definition. Moreover, the eigenvalues are not $6$ and $-4$.

Comment: Thank you for your remind. eigenvalues are 4 and -2.

Comment: @cecily exactly :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ associated to the eigenvector $v$, then $$A^mv = A^{m-1}Av = A^{m-1}\lambda v = \ldots = \lambda^m v,$$
i.e. $\lambda^m$ is an eigenvalue of $A^m$. Now, can you find the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: oh! I got it . And if the bases of eigenspace  of A^m is the same as that of A?

Comment: Yes, since, by the equation above, the eigenvectors of $A$ and $A^m$ are the same.

Comment: thank you  for your help .